# How to crop the image so that it fits 50% of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the image to fit the 50% of the ***screen height of the device*** and ***not 50% of the current screen size*** (the user might have minimized the screen). Also, when the user resizes the screen, I don't want the image to automatically fit the screen once initially it is rendered.

The image is very large and I am looking to **crop** it, and **not resize** it. Here is what I done so far:

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
</head>
<body>      
<img class="image" src="myimage.jpg" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

home.css:

```
html, body {
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
}

img.image {
width:100%;
}
```

I don't want to use anything apart from HTML, CSS and JavaScript. It would be great if somebody help me understand how should this be done in CSS. Thanks!

Comment: Define crop. A lot of people are assuming you want to resize the image.

Comment: By crop, I mean that the image should not be "compressed" to fit, instead, the overlapping part must be just cut off.

Comment: Let me know if you need help implementing my solution... like the JavaScript and such.

Comment: Of course I need. I am still attempting to do it with only CSS and not able to achieve it.

Comment: @user3614681 did you try my solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [css clip property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp).

Combining clip with a little JavaScript to get the screen size may just be the right solution.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. A lot of people seem to be confusing crop with resize.

Comment: @dotty its the only reason i posted it.

Answer (score 2):

to crop the image, you will need a container with overflow:hidden.
**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/riktF)**/example :

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.crop50h {
  height:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
/* some specific behavior for image ? */
.crop50h {
  text-align:center;
}
.crop50h img {
 /* width:100%;  ? */
  margin:0 -100%;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

Wit html basis :

```
<div class="crop50h">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've read your question correctly, I believe you're asking to set the image to be 50% of the desktop window, ***not*** the browser window.

In that case you can use `window.screen.availHeight` in Javascript to get the available height:

```
var half = window.screen.availHeight / 2;
var image = document.getElementByClassName("image")[0];

image.width=(half)+"px";
```

Comment: Where should I add this script into my HTML? I'm new to this and finding difficulty where to add it...

Comment: @user3614681 you want this to be at the bottom of your HTML page, body the closing `</body>` tag